# Get a data from another PowerShell console

Tags: powershell, console

For example, in the first PowerShell console, I run this code:

```
Start-Job { 
    Write-Host "Start Async Job"
    #Some code
}
```

After this I can use command:

```
Get-Job
```

And I'll get all list of Jobs.

But How can I get that Jobs from second PowerShell Console?
Because if I lock the first console, for example, for 10 minutes (Yes, I know that I can run it as a Job):

```
while($val -ne 10)
{
    #loop for 10 minutes
}
```

I have to wait when this while statement will finish.
So when the first console was locked, how can I get Jobs information from the second console?
Or there is some other idea. How can I get jobs if the main console is locked/used?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't.  They're in different runspace pools.

Comment: if You want to continue working on the "main console and use get-job|wait-job|receive-job"  kind of syntax to see when it's finished - You can consider starting Your jobs in separate process , pass all the relevant variables as parameters and have that console on the background and keep working on the "main" one. You will not be able to check progress on main console, but You might do something like get-job|receive-job every few seconds on second console to track the progress?

Comment: I need to track the progress of Jobs that were started in the main console, but which for example was blocked by a resource-intensive process.